# Android.Picasso не загружает картинку с интернета

Tags: java, android, picasso

Picasso не отображает картинку , а выдаёт "ошибочную" картинку . Вот java - класс программы :

```
package com.example.x.picassomodule;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Callback;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.mainImage);

        Picasso.with(this)
                .load("http://lifehacker.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/google-android-logo-green-black.jpg")
                .error(R.drawable.ic_warning_black_24dp)
                .into(imageView);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.x.picassomodule">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle(module:app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.x.picassomodule"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}
```

Xml(дизайн приложения):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mainImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Почему** картинка не загружается и **как** сделать что бы она загрузилась?

Comment: Интернет есть на устройстве? Добавьте коллбек. В его методе `onError` будет exception, который скажет, в чём ошибка загрузки.

Comment: Я с android - эмулятора запускал , он может подключится к сети установленной на компе?

Comment: скиньте стектрейс

Comment: Что такое стектрейс и как его скинуть?

Comment: Да, эмулятор использует сеть компьютера по умолчанию. Я же написал, добавьте колбек и узнаете в чём ошибка.

Comment: Уберите метод .error(...). и отпишитесь загружается картинка или нет.

Comment: @YaPV метод .error() убирал , также само картинка не загружается.

Comment: @eugeneek как вызвать ошибку в колбеке?

Comment: Не надо её вызывать. Просто добавьте коллбек и в методе onError вы получите исключение. Пишите там что-то типа `exception.printStackTrace()`. Стректрейс ошибки выводится в LogCat. Копируйте его и добавляйте в вопрос, если сами с ним не разберётесь.